# Liquibase preconditions with sequenceexists not working

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I'm trying to run liquibase on existing db, at that i'm facing error sequence already exists

```
<createSequence sequenceName="call_id_seq" schemaName="dw"/>
```

after i tried with preConditions, its not working as expected. I,m new to this liquibase,any one could you please suggest on this

```
<changeSet author="ashok" id="1443436437214-1">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <sequenceExists sequenceName="call_id_seq" schemaName="dw"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createSequence sequenceName="call_id_seq" schemaName="dw"/>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Hi @Ashok, have you resolved the problem? I'm currently having the same issue

Comment: Hi @dfche, I'm sorry, I didn't get any solution for this issue.

Comment: Hmm, it seems it's easier to use select from a service table to check for sequence existence as a workaround for this bug.

Comment: Same issue, seems like bug in liquibase. SqlCheck to the rescue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152899/1643115

Comment: I just referenced here: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1163#issuecomment-1235737915